# Find any letter at the end of a line, delete line break without replacing the target

Tags: regex, notepad++, bioinformatics, fasta

I'm trying to collapse several lines of letters to a single one.

Example

> ```
> >8445125
> VSSSDEQPRPRRS
> RNQDRQHPNQNRP
> VLGRTERDRNRRQ
> FGQNFLRDRKTIA
>
>
> >8445125
> VSSSDEQPRPRRSRNQDRQHPNQNRPVLGRTERDRNRRQFGQNFLRDRKTIA
> ```

I've tried regex Find [A-Z]\n Replace with blank. Problem is that it would delete the S, P Q and A that are at the end of each line. I need to do this without deleting those letters.

In a given file, I would have >1000 of the above.

Comment: why not just replace `\n` or `\n$`?

Comment: otherwise if you want to ensure that the character before the newline is in `[A-Z]` try a positive lookbehind `(?<=[A-Z])\n` as that is a zero width assertion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your regular expression to the following. The `\K` escape sequence resets the starting point of the reported match and any previously consumed characters are no longer included.

```
Find: [A-Z]\K\n
```

Comment: Couldn't yet. Timelimit. [A-Z]\K\n worked great. \n doesn't work because then it puts the numbers (which is the name) immediately before the sequence (letters)